# Query building with Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to code a search functionality which not only allows me to search by a category of a question but also by its content. I'm using PostgreSQL and its `ts_vector` capabilities for the content. For the categories, I want to use Laravel's Eloquent and Query Builder.

The content search is fully working, but I can't figure out how to limit the displayed questions to the ones with those categories. This is what I have so far:

```
$questions = Question::search($query_string)->paginate(NUM_PER_PAGE);
```

I also have an array of strings which are category names (`$tag_names`). As you can see from the schema each name is `unique`.

This is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE questions (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES commentables(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    correct_answer BIGINT UNIQUE,
    search tsvector
);

CREATE TABLE categories (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    description TEXT,
    num_posts INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE questions_categories (
    question_id BIGINT REFERENCES questions(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    category_id INTEGER REFERENCES categories(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (question_id, category_id)
);
```

I've created the Model Classes for each of the database tables, so you can refer to them by `Question`, `Category` and `QuestionsCategory`.

Comment: What is inside the `search` method?

Comment: @HelderLucas It's a built-in Laravel method. It makes use of a function defined by me which returns a Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.

Comment: Did you define any relationships?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir No, I didn't. I've looked it up but didn't quite understand how it would help in this case.

Comment: Please, regard `$query_string` definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `categories` relationship in your `Question` model:

```
public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'questions_categories')
}
```

Then extend your query:

```
$questions = Question::search($query_string)
    ->whereHas('categories', function($query) use($categoryIds) {
        $query->whereIn('id', $categoryIds);
    })->paginate(NUM_PER_PAGE);
```

Comment: It worked but it's worth noting for future reference that the order matters and I had to first query with the `whereHas` and only then apply the `search` method.

Comment: Do you know how to apply an `and` instead of an `or`? If I input 2 tags I want that question to have those 2 tags simultaneously instead of at least one of them.